# How to invite user to a team using Graph API?

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I can invite a user with Graph API `/invitations` endpoint:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations
Content-type: application/json

{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "admin@fabrikam.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.contoso.com",
  "sendInvitationMessage": true
}
```

In this cas a mail is sent to the invited user. It is OK.

I can add this user to a team with `/teams/<team-id>/members` endpoint. But it does not send invitation email to the user.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/<team-id>/members
Content-type: application/json

{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
    "roles": ["guest"],
    "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('<user-id>')"
}
```

The `/invitations` endpoint does not have any options to set team-id the user is invited to.

When I add a user to a team using MS Teams application then the user automatically receives an invitation mail containing the URL of the team the user is invited to.

I can send an invitation mail using `/invitations` endpoint anytime. But this mail contains only the domain the user is created. It does not contain the URL of the team the user is has been added.

How can I send an invitation mail containing the URL of the team the user is added to?

Comment: per my understand, if the user you want to invite is a work/school account, and his account has a teams license, then after you invite the user, the user will automatically joined in the team...

Comment: What about guest users who has personal account only?

Comment: I don't know.. But I know when we want tot download teams, there are 2 options, personal or work/school account, so I'm afraid it is impossible to do it.https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw4a0.png

Comment: Using /invitations endpoint, we add guest users to our tenant and then we can add them to our Team using /teams/<team-id>/members endpoint. So, it is not possible to send an invitation mail containing the URL of the team the user is added to with /invitations endpoint.

Comment: I see /invitations endpoint cannot send mail containing URL of the team the user is added to. Bu I thoungh /teams/<team_id>/members endpoint send this incitation mail as a common Teams service.
Anytime I can call /invitations endpoint to send invitation mail to a user. I can also set personalized message. Can I set formatted (HTML) message (containing the URL of the team) to this invitation mail?

Answer (score 0):

We got an update from the engineering team saying, adding a member to the team won't send invitation. Only invite API sends invitation email. Also, currently It is not possible to send message with HTML formatting.